# acess the get parameters in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

If I have a page say

```
www.google.com?search=angular
```

and I need to access the *search= angular* which is the get parameters for the page. how should I do it? 
Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're injected $location into the controller, service, etc. where you need this information, then something like:

```
var params = $location.search()
```

will give you an array of the URL parameters.